# Why does RTD run "python env create" instead of "conda env create" when building?

Tags: python, read-the-docs

I have a project on ReadTheDocs that I'm trying to build.  I'm using a very basic `.readthedocs.yaml` file that reads:

```
# .readthedocs.yaml
# Read the Docs configuration file
# See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html for details

# Required
version: 2

# Set the version of Python and other tools you might need
build:
  os: ubuntu-20.04
  tools:
    python: "3.9"
    # You can also specify other tool versions:
    # nodejs: "16"
    # rust: "1.55"
    # golang: "1.17"

# Build documentation in the docs/ directory with Sphinx
sphinx:
  builder: html
  configuration: docs/source/conf.py
  fail_on_warning: true

# If using Sphinx, optionally build your docs in additional formats such as PDF
# formats:
#    - pdf

# Optionally declare the Python requirements required to build your docs
python:
   install:
   - requirements: docs/requirements.txt

conda:
  environment: environment.yml
```

Unfortunately, the RTD build logs seem to tell me that after cloning and writing out the `environment.yml` file, the build process runs `python env create --quiet --name develop --file environment.yml`. This obviously fails with "no such file or directory" (Error 2) since, well, no such file or directory as `env` exists in the directory structure.  Shouldn't RTD be running `conda create` here?  How do I make it do the right thing?

Thanks,
Eli

Comment: I have no idea, but I would start with reading their docs: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/conda.html. I would also use a minimal setup and incrementally add parts to isolate where things break.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is described in https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/8595

In summary, `python: "3.9"` now means that CPython 3.9 + venv are used, regardless of `conda.environment`.

If one wants to use a conda environment, `python: "miniconda3-4.7"` or `python: "mambaforge-4.10"` need to be specified.

In the future, a better error message should be shown at least. Feel free to upvote the issue.